# Constant and changing content embedded in Wordpress Post?

Tags: html, wordpress

I need two pages embeded side by side in a Wordpress post.  The left page must be able to operate independently of the right, and vice-versa.  The content on the left page changes (like flipping through pages of the site), but the content on the right HAS to stay constant....not even a page refresh.  I also need the page on the right to remain visible.  The page on the right is a virtual environment, while the page on the left contains instructions for the reader to complete a particular task in the environment.  Ideally, the instructions woud be broken into steps, the steps into pages. So, you'd end up with something like page 1 on left, virtual environment on right, click continue....page 2 on left, no change to virtual environment page.  Hopefully that all makes sense.

Thus far, I've tried embedding with iframes.  I've come close, but the @#@!@# page on the right keeps refreshing itself when the page on the left changes.  Because of how all this is setup, really all I can do is embed the page itself in itself if that makes sense (basically something like iframe src="#").  That works, but when I add the virtual environment on the right, it gets added to the left as well.

If anyone is familiar with katacoda scenarios, that's pretty much exactly what I am trying to pull off here.  The best way I can explain it, divide your screen in half vertically.  Left half content changes, right half content remains static.

So, I know this is possible.  What's the best way to pull it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you actually do not want the second page to be refreshing or anything and you want it to be constant, why don't you just create a scrollable element and put all the elements from the web page you would like, without using an iframe. This way it will be a constant. Other than that, I believe your code looks something like that? :

```
  <iframe src="link_v1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"                        
      style="height: 100%; width: 49%; float: left; " 
           height="100%" width="49%" align="left">
                          </iframe>  



<iframe src="link_v2" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="overflow: hidden; 
 height: 100%;width:49%; "height="100%" width="49%" align="right">
                                </iframe>
```

Check it out here too: https://codepen.io/war_lock1221/pen/XMzXWb

Comment: Yes, that is the code I have.  It works, right up until you try to switch pages on the left.  When you do that, the page on the right refreshes, connecton closed, game over.  If a mod could close this for me I'd appreciate it.  Without re-writing the involved plugins, and most likely the theme as well, use case is simply not possible.

Comment: Well, that’s why you can just make the right page as a <div> element with overflow:scroll and the width and height of the page, with a border, not an iframe, but I think you should use AJAX for loading only one of the pages, since you may decide you want more than two pages.